# How to assign value of PrimaryKey(generated using sequence) to another variable while persisting with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have implemented a customised sequence based generator which generates primary key of an entity. I want to assign same value  to another member variable while persisting the entity. Is there anyway this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `@PostPersist` annotated method. To keep things simple, let me just use an auto generated id.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long idDup;

    // Getters and setters removed for brevity

    @PostPersist
    public void perPersist() {
        this.idDup = id;
    }
}
```

From the documentation:

> @PostPersist is executed after the entity manager persist operation is actually
>   executed or cascaded. This call is invoked after the database INSERT
>   is executed.

Note that `@PostPersist` is a JPA annotation hence would work on all providers.

Comment: Actually other member variable is also a column in the table. I want both of them to get persisted with the same value.

Comment: Yes, in the example above, `idDup` is a column of `PERSON` table. Is it not?

Comment: Sorry , I have one more doubt here. Documentation says that @PostPersist is executed after database inserted is called. Then how will both columns have same value in the database?

Comment: :) Thats because you are updating the member on `this` which is a managed entity after persistance.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the other column is not getting updated with Id's value. Class itself is annotated with @Transaction so no need to do entitymanager.flush afterwards, right?